# Configuring Full framework assemblies called by Asp.Net Core 2.0 App?

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, .net-assembly, appsettings

I am working on ASP.NET Core web site. My website has a reference on a full framework assembly that uses configuration application settings coming from an old fashioned web.config file, There is no control over this assembly and the code can not be fixed and recompiled

Config file that looks like

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="marketDataServiceEndpointName" value="UatMarketDataService"/>
</appSettings>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="DebugBinding"/>
  </basicHttpBinding>
  <netTcpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceNetTcp" 
             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
              sendTimeout="10:00:00" 
             closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" 
             receiveTimeout="10:00:00">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>

    <binding name="loggingService" sendTimeout="00:05:00">
      <security mode="None"/>
    </binding>
  </netTcpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint 
     address="net.tcp://localhost/Service/Service.svc" 
     binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="loggingService" 
     contract="ServiceContracts.IService" name="IVisionLoggingService"/>
  <endpoint 
  address="http://localhost:62698/Service.svc" 
  binding="basicHttpBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="DebugBinding" 
   contract="Service.IService" name="DebugBinding"/>
</client>
```

I've tried to provide a config file for the assembly like
"MyAssemblyName.dll.config" with all the config parameters.
Unfortunately it seems not reading the config file

Comment: i dont think you can use it. wcf is not part of .net standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core does not have the configuration system of .NET Framework based on .config files so they won't be respected. Without additional support libraries, calls to the `System.Configuration` types will even fail at runtime. There is a [new configuration system](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration) built around the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` and related NuGet packages. (which can even be used outside of .NET Core / ASP.NET Core)

Also note that .NET Core 2.0 doesn't have any server-side WCF service hosting capability so what you were trying to accomplish wouldn't work even through some other configuration system.

Comment: asp.net core on .net core: only a subset that is supported. not wcf. For that you can still use asp.net core on .net framework.